# Fixed Point Property of $(0,1]$

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Does $(0,1]$ have Fixed-point property? I can't wrap my head around any examples of continous map $f:(0,1]\rightarrow(0,1]$ that doesn't have fixed point.

Comment: Note that $(0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $[0,\infty)$ - does *that* have the fixed point property? (Think about addition ...)

Comment: Have you tried to draw any pictures?

Answer (score 3):

$f:(0,1] \to (0,1]$ defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x$ has no fixed point.

Comment: well yeah, i thought about those and this map is $f:(0,1]\rightarrow(0,\frac{1}{2}]$ doesnt it have to be $(0,1]\rightarrow(0,1]$?

Comment: The map isn’t required to be onto.

Comment: okay i get it now, thank you!